# HTML5 input secure ssl

Tags: html, ssl, input

I have an input tag like:

```
<input type="url" id="inputWebsite" name="url">
```

I need to ensure that the value the user enters contains a secure url like *https://*
How can I do it ?

Comment: Where do you put that code? Inside the <head> tag or the <body> tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using this:

```
<input type="url" name="website" id="inputWebsite" required pattern="https://.+">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use pattern in html5 url tag:

```
<input type="url" pattern="https?://.+" required />
```

In the papper Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax [RFC3986] http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt the regular expression for a URI is:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

For example, matching the above expression to

```
  http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
```

results in the following subexpression matches:

```
  $1 = http:
  $2 = http
  $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
  $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
  $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
  $6 = <undefined>
  $7 = <undefined>
  $8 = #Related
  $9 = Related
```